# For loop hang submit form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I created a form that generate dictionary word randomly. When i submit form and it show me that word in text area  it hang my page and stop working every thing that is below in textarea like footer or anything is not shown.How can i make it correct below is my code.

```
    $str = "";
    $characters = array_merge(range($a_r,$a_r2), range($w_r,$w_r2));
    $max = count($characters) - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $rand = mt_rand(0, $max);
    $str .= $characters[$rand];
    }
    return $str;

    }

    function Show(100000,$length,$a_r,$a_r2,$w_r,$w_r2){
      for($i=0; $i<100000; $i++)
      {
      echo randomString($length,$a_r,$a_r2,$w_r,$w_r2)."<br>";
       }

    }
```

Comment: Your code isn't complete. You used `return` whiling isn't in any `function`.

Comment: where is jQuery/JavaScript here?

Comment: i am not using any jquery or javascript this is simple php html form